# How to report an Android app clone on Google Play (piracy)

Tags: android, google-play, piracy

Someone copied my game [Minesweeper 3D](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiirecords.minesweeper3d) and republished it on Google Play with the same name, description, resources, etc. Only the logo and icon were changed!

I checked the other apps from the same "developer" and they are all copies.

This question is not about how to prevent piracy, it is about how to formally report this developer/publisher to Google.

*I'm not posting the link here to avoid additional traffic/downloads for these apps*

Comment: Your question should probably be asked in a more appropriate forum, perhaps Google has one to ask in. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: So what happened?

Comment: They removed it after a few hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a [page](https://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1114905&page=ts.cs) that will walk you through the process of requesting a take down on any of its services, including Google Play.

Comment: Request sent, let's see what happens! Thanks!

Comment: @thiagolr I also have same can you please guide me how can i get rid of from such problem